# JavaScript HTML PHP MySQL modeling(code to UML specifically)

Tags: xampp, uml

I have a xampp application that I want to model either automatically from code or manually, how does one model such an application generally and how to do it from existing code, my search results for code to UML only include either PHP or other languages alone but no results for an intertwined xampp application. Thanks in advance for all contributors.